# Is $c_{00}$ closed in $(\ell^\infty,\|\cdot\|_∞)$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Consider the normed space $(X,\|\cdot\|)= (\ell^\infty,\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ and its linear subspace $V = c_{00}$ consisting of all sequences $(a_n)_{n≥1}$ of real numbers that eventually become zero:
$(a_n)_{n≥1} ∈V \iff ∃N$ such that for all $k ≥ N, a_k = 0$.

Is $V$ closed in $(\ell^\infty,\|\cdot\|_∞)$? Justify your answer.

---

I'm confused on what we have to show. Do we just see if $V$ is a closed set? So do we see if $V-X$ is open?

Is there a general way to do these because I find them very hard to follow.

Answer (score 2):

You need to ask yourself, is $V$ is a closed subspace of $X$? Namely, given a sequence $v_n\in V$ such that for some $v\in X$, $\|v_n-v\|_\infty\to0$, does that imply that $v\in V$ as well?

(You could try and show that $X\setminus V$ is open, but that's harder.)

Comment: Well we know from lectures that the infinity normed space is a Banach space, so it satisfies the completeness axiom. Does that help in any way?

Comment: Wait, $v$ is going to be a constant right? So this can never be in V since it doesn't converge to zero at any certain point...

Comment: Given any $x\in X$, what would be the obvious candidate for a sequence converging to it in $V$? Now, it's clear that something like $x=\langle 1,1,1,\ldots\rangle$ won't work. But why?

Comment: $x=(1,1,...)$ wont work because it doesn't converge (let alone converge to zero). We can pick something like $x=(1,...1,0,0,...)$ right?

Comment: @snowman: Yes, but this seqence is in $V$ already.

Comment: @snowman: Yes, but as Roland wrote. We're not trying to approximate an element of $V$ with a sequence from $V$, that's irrelevant. We're trying to approximate an element of $X$ with a sequence of elements of $V$. So what would go wrong in approximating $\langle 1,1,1,\ldots\rangle$ with the obvious choice of a sequence of approximations from $V$? (And what would that obvious choice be?)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sorry for the lateness. So you want me to pick a vector x in X such that $||v_n-x||_{\infty}$ goes wrong, with our sequence of vectors $v_n$ in $V$. What do you mean by "approximate"? I am guessing this obvious choice is the zero vector? It normally is, have no idea what we are even doing though!!!#

Comment: @AsafKaragila Let $v_n=(1,...,1,0,0,...) \in c_{00}$ and $v=(1,...,1,1/n,1/n,...) \in \ell^{\infty}$. So $||v_n-v||_{\infty}=||(0,...,0,1/n,1/n,...)||_{\infty}=\sup |1/n| =0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. But $v$ is not in $c_{00}$ so it is not closed?

Comment: @snowman: Think. If you you had to approximate a convergent sequence by finite sequences, how would you have approximated it? It's also not a big deal to approximate $0$, since it is an element of the subspace. First understand what do I mean by approximate, then understand why it goes wrong when you try "the obvious approximation" on something which does not approach to $0$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila So do we specifically choose what $v_n \in V$ is? And do we also specifically choose what $v \in X$ is?

Comment: @snowman: Forget all this. If you wanted to show that the rational numbers are not closed by using a sequence, how would you do it? Take $\pi$, take $p_n$ to be the first $n$ digits of $\pi$'s decimal expansion, and conclude that since $\pi$ is irrational, the sequence is convergent but the limit is not in $\Bbb Q$. Here it's the same thing. We want to find a sequence in $c_{00}$ which is convergent, but the limit is not in $c_{00}$. What does it mean that a sequence in $\ell_\infty$ is convergent? What does it mean for the sequence in $c_{00}$, then?

Comment: @AsafKaragila What does it mean that a sequence $(a_n)$ in $\ell^{\infty}$ is convergent? There exists some $N$ such that $|a_n|<1$ for all $n>N$. What does it mean for the sequence $(a_n)$ to be in $c_{00}$? That there exists some $M$ such that $a_n=0$ for all $n>M$.

Comment: @snowman: You're mixing a sequence and an element. It's a bit confusing, I agree, when you talk about sequences of sequences.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I dunno I give up. Been trying this for many hours now!

Comment: @AsafKaragila what if we had $v_n=(0,0,...) \in V$ and $(1-n,1-n,...) \in \ell^{\infty}$ then $||v_n-v||=||(1-n, 1-n,...)||=\sup_{n \in \mathbb N}|1-n|=0$? $v$ is not in $c_{00}$ so it is not closed.

Comment: @snowman: You're reversing the definition of closed.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Can you please show me the answer because I am stressed out with this now...............

Answer (score 0):

The closure of $c_{00}$ in $\ell_{\infty} $ is equal to $c_0$- the space of sequences tending to $0.$

Comment: This is a correct statement that may serve as a very good hint for the OP. No reason for down-voting.